# Is it possible to add code to controls added in a style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've used styles many times to extend the functionality of a control. For instance if you have a control to collect data from a Person, and you want to use it for other class Student which inherits from Person but has some additional fields, you can add those fields to the default style and bind the control to the Student instance.

But right now I need to add a button to load a file and store the path in a property of the class that is the `DataContext` of the control. That's why I need to add code for the button behavior.

I wonder if it's possible to add C# code to a control that is defined in a style. I guess the answer is no but I'm no expert.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you might be able to achieve this with an attached behaviour: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF

Comment: @benPearce I'm reading the article. It's sounds promising. Thank's a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Actually **Attached Behavior** is the solution to this question. Using this technique you can inject code to Controls that you are unable to modify.

In this case I have a button inside a style, I want to attach an event handler to the `Click Event`. The first consist of creating the behavior as a `Dependency Property`, later we need to set this `Dependency Property` in the `Button`.

```
class OpenFileDialogOnClickBehavior
{
    public static bool GetOpenFileDialogOnClick(Button button)
    {
        return (bool)button.GetValue(OpenFileDialogOnClickProperty);
    }

    public static void SetOpenFileDialogOnClick(Button button, bool value)
    {
        button.SetValue(OpenFileDialogOnClickProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenFileDialogOnClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "OpenFileDialogOnClick",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(OpenFileDialogOnClickBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnOpenFileDialogOnClick));

    static void OnOpenFileDialogOnClick(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = depObj as Button;
        if (button == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            button.Click += OnClick;
        else
            button.Click -= OnClick;
    }

    static void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only react to the Click event raised by the Button. Ignore all ancestors
        // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Click fired.
        if (!ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

        Button button = e.OriginalSource as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            // Open File Dialog or any action to react to the Click Event.
        }
    }
}
```

Now set the property in the `Button`

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:OpenFileDialogOnClickBehavior.OpenFileDialogOnClick" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>

<!-- Code of the style... -->
```

I used the link provided in comment by **benPearce** to create this answer. There is a more detailed description there.